# Error while converting tuples to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

When i try to convert tuples to pandas dataframe i get the following error:

> DataFrame constructor not properly called!

I am using the following code

```
columnlist=["Timestamp","Price","Month","Day","DayofWeek","tDaysleftMonth","tDayinMonth","tDayinWeek"]
tickerData=pd.DataFrame(tickerDataRaw,columns=columnlist)
```

The data was loaded to tuples from a MySQL database ,

Please find a screenshot of the data. [Data I am trying to convert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enIfY.png)

Comment: I am using the following code
columnlist=["Timestamp","Price","Month","Day","DayofWeek","tDaysleftMonth","tDayinMonth","tDayinWeek"]
tickerData=pd.DataFrame(tickerDataRaw,columns=columnlist)

Answer (score 7):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) with converting `tuples` to `list`:

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = ((1,2,3),(4,6,7),(7,3,6),(8,2,7),(4,6,3),(7,3,6))

columnlist = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(list(tuples), columns=columnlist)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  6  7
2  7  3  6
3  8  2  7
4  4  6  3
5  7  3  6
```

Another solution with `DataFrame` constructor only:

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = ((1,2,3),(4,6,7),(7,3,6),(8,2,7),(4,6,3),(7,3,6))

columnlist = ['a','b','c']
df = pd.DataFrame(list(tuples), columns=columnlist)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  6  7
2  7  3  6
3  8  2  7
4  4  6  3
5  7  3  6
```

EDIT:

If check [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) and parameter `data`:

> **data** : numpy ndarray (structured or homogeneous), dict, or DataFrame
>
> Dict can contain Series, arrays, constants, or list-like objects

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Dataframe documentation page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html), data is required to be

> numpy ndarray (structured or homogeneous), dict, or DataFrame

The easiest way to resolve your problem is simplty load your data in a *numpy array* and it should work fine.

```
>>> tuples = ((1,2,3),(1,2,3),(1,2,3))
>>> columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> pd.DataFrame(tuples, columns=columns)
PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

>>> pd.DataFrame(np.array(tuples), columns=columns)
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  3
2  1  2  3
```